# Recurse through tree to create a list of breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a tree of data and am trying to create a recursive function to add each path in the tree as an array of strings to better understand recursion.  I am not sure why my method is not producing the expect

```js
var tree = {
 "name": "home",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "cars",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "ford",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "mustang"
      },
      {
       "name": "explorer"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "food",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "pizza"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};

var list = [];
var path = [];

function traverse(node) {
    if (node.name) { 
        path.push(node.name) 
    }
    
    if (!node.children) { 
        if (path.length) {
            list.push(path);
        }
        return; 
    } else {
     node.children.forEach(function(item) {
       traverse(item); 
     });  
    }
}

traverse(tree);
console.log(list);
```

The output I am looking to create is:

```
[
    ["home"],
    ["home", "cars"],
    ["home", "cars", "ford"],
    ["home", "cars", "ford", "mustang"],
    ["home", "cars", "ford", "explorer"],
    ["home", "food"],
    ["home", "food", "pizza"]
]
```

Comment: Well for one thing you are storing the path variable outside the recursive function and never resetting its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You modify the same `path` array in all iterations. You should copy it instead:

```
var list = [];
function traverse(node, path) {
  if ( !path )
    path = [];
  if (node.name) {
    path.push(node.name)
  }
  list.push(path);
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach(function(item) {
      traverse(item, path.slice());
    });
  }
}
traverse(tree, []);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize I was modifying the same array.

Comment: should `list.push(path);` not be in the condition above?

Comment: Yes, there is a pending edit for this post that should fix this

Comment: The edit is unrelated to `list.push(path)` and was not necessary because I passed `[]` as a second argument. `list.push(path)` might need to be moved indeed depending on the desired behavior when some objects don't have a `name` property.

Answer (score 4):

I have corrected your code, this solution copies the `path` variable from one function call to the other:

```js
var tree = {
  "name": "home",
  "children": [{
    "name": "cars",
    "children": [{
      "name": "ford",
      "children": [{
        "name": "mustang"
      }, {
        "name": "explorer"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "food",
    "children": [{
      "name": "pizza"
    }]
  }]
};

var path = [];

var list = [];
function traverse(node, path) {
  if ( !path )
    path = [];
  if (node.name) {
    path.push(node.name)
  }
  list.push(path);
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach(function(item) {
      traverse(item, path.slice());
    });
  }
  document.write(JSON.stringify(path )+ '<br>')
}
traverse(tree, []);
```